# how to get rid of sound when pressing a button android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I press buttons in my app in Android studio, there is always a soft thud sound. I think it is there by default. How do I get rid of it or change it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to disable the sound

```
thebutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

or you can do it through xml

```
 <Button... android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a code in XML. Not even change programmatically.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the sound through XML, by adding just one line

android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"

```
<Button
    ....
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
  />
```